# How to dynamically name my object params in this lodash loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, lodash

https://lodash.com/docs#find

```
var params = {};

_.forEach(n.tags, function(n, index) {
    console.log(index);
    index++

    // For each tag, create new param.term1, term2, term3 etc...
    params.term[index] = _.result(_.find(n.tags, function(term_id) {
        return term_id;
    }), 'term_id');
});
```

The `_.forEach` will loop over `n.tags` (which contains up to 3 tags).

I iterate the `index++` by 1 so I start with 1 not 0, to create "term1".

Now the next part is where I'm trying to dynamically generate up to 3 new params.term[i] values.

```
params.term[index] = _.result(_.find(n.tags, function(term_id) {
    return term_id;
}), 'term_id');
```

What I'm trying to get is the following:

```
params.term1 = 111;
params.term2 = 222;
params.term3 = 333;
```

The error I'm currently getting is **TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined** when I try to dynamically set the param name here: `params.term[index]`

How would you accomplish this using `_lodash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to `params.term` as an existing array, which is why you're getting an error.  Try this instead...

```
params["term" + index] = ....
```

That will create a property for each index instead.  You can either access it with

```
params["term1"]
```

or...

```
params.term1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set `params.term[1]`, `params.term[2]`, `and params.term[3]`. This would work if `params.term` were an array, but it seems that in fact, `params.term` doesn't exist.

You said you want to set `params.term1`, `params.term2`, and `params.term3`, so you should do instead the following to programmatically access to the fields `term1`, `term2` and `term3`.

```
params["term" + index] = _.result(_.find(n.tags, function(term_id) {
    return term_id;
}), 'term_id');
```

Comment: Thanks! Ah that's what I was missing, and you are correct, params.term did not exist.